# Cannot update the data in ASPxGridControl

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I found that I cannot update the data in my second grid when I clicked on the first grid control.

There are two grids in my program and there is overloaded function GetDataTable2() to get DataTable according to the focused row in grid1.

However, I dun know why the grid2 cannot be updated.

Please help!

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gv1.DataSource = GetDataTable1();
        gv1.KeyFieldName = "ID";
        gv1.DataBind();

        gv2.DataSource = GetDataTable2();
        gv2.DataBind();
    }



    protected void gv1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gv2.DataSource = GetDataTable2((int)gv1.GetRowValues(gv1.FocusedRowIndex, "ID"));
        gv2.DataBind();
    }
```

And the asp.net:

```
<body> 
  <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager> 
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
    <ContentTemplate> 
      <div>
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gv1" runat="server"  SettingsBehavior-AllowFocusedRow="true" SettingsBehavior-ProcessFocusedRowChangedOnServer="true" OnFocusedRowChanged="gv1_FocusedRowChanged"  >
      </div>  
      <div>
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gv2" runat="server"   >
      </div> 
    </ContentTemplate> 
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Need to see more markup code - are they in updatepanels?

Comment: yes, they are.


`<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div>*******grid 1 here *********</div>

<div>*******grid 2 here *********</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel></form>
</body>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you set the ASPxGridView's [EnableCallbacks](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_EnableCallBackstopic) property to false, your code will start working properly.  This is the recommended way of using ASPxGridView when it is located within the MS UpdatePanel.

Comment: Are you the staff from DevExpress?
Do you know how to set the notification Email off for the ticket?

Comment: You know... they are so annoying to me

Comment: @Tony, you should login to your account on DevExpress.com, go to My Account-->Manage Your Profile, scroll down and change the Email Settings :)

Comment: Can I make it ticket specific?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the UpdatePanel.
In the first grid, use the "RowClick" client side event and perform a callback in the second grid.

ClientSide Event

```
function gv1_RowClick(s, e) {
    gv2.PerformCallback("UPDATE_SECOND_GRID|" + gv1.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex));
}
```

ServerSide Event

```
protected void gv2_CustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e) 
{
    string[] args = e.Parameters.Split('|');
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        return;

    if (args[0].Equals("UPDATE_SECOND_GRID")) {
        //your code with args[1] (key of the first grid)
        gv2.DataSource = GetDataTable2();
        gv2.DataBind();
    }     
}
```